# (At least 2) Binomial Distribution Question

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations, binomial-coefficients, binomial-distribution

Question:

Eggs are sold in boxes of six and it is likely that 1% of the eggs will be broken when they are unpacked. Find:

(i) the probability that a box contains no broken eggs
(ii) the probability that a box contains no more than one broken egg

I buy four boxes. Find:

(iii) the probability that I get no broken eggs
(iv) the probability that I have at least two broken eggs

I know the answer to the first 3 questions:

(i) 0.9415
(ii) 0.9985
(iii) 0.7857

But the fourth one is killing me!

Could you show the steps of the answers as well? Thank you so much!!!

Comment: You can find the probability of no broken eggs, which happen to be (iii) and the probability of 1 broken egg. The probability you wish to find is exactly $1$ minus the aforementioned probability associated to these two scenarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $p=1\%=0.01$ we have
$$
P(\left\{\text{$k$ of $n$ eggs broken}\right\})=\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}
$$
Knowing this, you can evaluate
$$\begin{align}
P(\{\text{$0$ of $6$ eggs broken}\})&=\binom{6}{0}p^0(1-p)^{6-0}=(1-p)^6\tag{$i$}\\
P(\{\text{$0$ or $1$ of $6$ eggs broken}\})&=P(\{\text{$0$ of $6$ eggs broken}\})+P(\{\text{$1$ of $6$ eggs broken}\})\\&=\binom{6}{0}p^0(1-p)^{6-0}+\binom{6}{1}p^1(1-p)^{6-1}\\&=(1-p)^6+6p(1-p)^5\tag{ii}\\
P(\{\text{$0$ of $24$ eggs broken}\})&=\binom{24}{0}p^0(1-p)^{24-0}=(1-p)^{24}\tag{$iii$}\\
P(\{\text{more than $1$ of $24$ eggs broken}\})&=1-P(\{\text{$0$ or $1$ of $24$ eggs broken}\})\\&=1-\binom{24}{0}p^0(1-p)^{24-0}-\binom{24}{1}p^1(1-p)^{24-1}\\&=1-(1-p)^{24}-24p(1-p)^{23}\tag{iv}
\end{align}$$